# Why the dictionary isn't showing affected values?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, type-conversion, pcap

I have this function that converts a dictionary in Python in a `.json` format.

```
def json_read(filename):
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        json.dump(HANDSHAKE, f)
```

The dictionary is called HANDSHAKE and it's in another `.py` file.

`output_dictionary.py`:

```
HANDSHAKE = {
    "Client_Hello" : {
        'Handshake Type': 'unknown',
        'Length': 'unknown',
        'Version': 'unknown',
        'Random': 'unknown',
        'Session ID': 'unknown',
        'Session ID Length': 'unknown',
        'Cipher Suites': 'unknown',
        'Compression Method': 'unknown'
        },
    "Server_Hello" : {
        'Handshake Type': 'unknown',
        'Length': 'unknown',
        'Version': 'unknown',
        'Random': 'unknown',
        'Session ID': 'unknown',
        'Session ID Length': 'unknown',
        'Ciphe Suite': 'unknown',
        'Compression Method': 'unknown'
        }
    }
```

I want to fill the dictionary with the data captured by packets. An example for Client Hello is the code below:

```
def parse_client_hello(handshake):
    if isinstance(handshake.data, dpkt.ssl.TLSClientHello):
        client = dpkt.ssl.TLSClientHello(str(handshake.data))
        HANDSHAKE["Client_Hello"]['Version'] = tls_dictionary('tls_version',client.version)
        session_id, pointer = parse(client.data, 1)
        HANDSHAKE["Client_Hello"]['Session ID'] = hexlify(session_id))
        ciphersuites, pointer1 = parse(client.data[pointer:], 2)
        ciphersuites, pretty_cipher_suites = parse_extension(ciphersuites, 'cipher_suites')
        HANDSHAKE["Client_Hello"]['Cipher Suites'] = pretty_cipher_suites
        HANDSHAKE["Client_Hello"]['Random'] = client.random
        pointer += pointer1
        compression_methods, pointer1 = parse(client.data[pointer:], 1)
        compression_methods, pretty_compressions = parse_extension(compression_methods,
            'compression_methods')
        HANDSHAKE["Client_Hello"]['Compression Method'] = pretty_compressions
```

This function normally should "fill" the dictionary with the data that I want to, but when I do a

```
cat output_dictionary.py
```

The data hasn't changed at all, the dictionary still has the initialized data which has the value `"unknown"`.
How can I change the dictionary values , so that I can then convert it directly into .`json` format using the `json_read` function?

**ADDED:**

I have this function that sniffs packets in a constant loop using pcap library in Python.

```
def interface_listening(interface):
    try:
        packets = pcap.pcap(name=interface)
    except OSError as exception:
        print('[-] Issue: {0}'.format(exception))
        sys.exit(-1)
    while True:
        print('[+] Listening on interface {0}'.format(packets.name))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        packets.loop(0, ethernet_parse) #constant loop
```

The prototype of `packets.loop` is that it takes a callback function, in this case: `ethernet_parse`.

I do some parsing of the packets order by order , which means: Ethernet, Ip, Tcp until I arrive at TLS information. The goal is to extract some Client Hello information with `parse_client_hello` function and output the data as a .json format.

My goal is to fill out this dictionary with the captured data in `parse_client_hello` function for each packet, and to use the `json_read` function in order to have a file that contains all the captured data of `"Client Hello"` printed as a `.json` format.

My question is: Where should I call the `json_read` function? If I call it just right after `packets.loop` of `interface_listening function`, it is never called.

Comment: is the isinstance function in parse_client_hello evaluating to True?

Comment: Just changing the `HANDSHAKE` dictionary in memory will not change the file's contents unless you call the `json_read()` to **write** the file — the function's name to actually the exact opposite of what it does.

Comment: @martineau The problem is that my code is capturing packets in a constant loop and analyzing them at the same tile. I use pcap library in python to do this by calling pcap.pcap.loop. Do you have any idea of where should i call the json_read() function?
I am adding some code so you can understand my question

Comment: @martineau I would be really grateful if you could answer to my question

Comment: Alicia, nobody on this site *owes* you an answer.  You'll just need to be patient.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not at all familiar with the `pcap` module — that said, it's completely unclear (to me anyway) how the `json_read()` function would fit into the scheme of things.

Comment: @martineau json_read() is needed only to convert the data in a .json format. That is all the function is supposed to do.

Comment: I can tell what it does, just not how it's supposed be called and by what.

Comment: @martineau It is supposed to be called after the Client Hello information is parsed in each captured packet by parse_client_hello function

Comment: Ideally you should call the `json_read()` function once, after all that data have been added to the `HANDSHAKE` dictionary. You _could_ call it multiple times, but each time it will overwrite any existing contents it had.

Comment: @martineau yes that's what I have tried, I called json_read("file.txt") at the end of parse_client_hello() (because that's where the filling of the dictionary ends). The result in the file.txt has the initialized values, it doesn't take the supposed values.

Comment: @martineau So it means that the json_read function doesn't take the values of the filled dictionary in memory, but insted it takes the values of output_dictionary.py

Comment: No, `json_read()` won't ever "take" the values of the existing file. Sounds like the `HANDSHAKE` dictionary wasn't updated — so you need to determine _why_ it isn't happening.

Comment: So it is normal that the output_dictionary.py isn't updated? @martineau

Comment: And it is not normal that the dictionary in memory is not updated, is that right? @martineau

Comment: Not sure what "normal" means (since I don't know `pcap`) — only that unless something like `parse_client_hello()` gets called somehow (or some other code somewhere modifies it), then obviously its contents in memory won't change.

Comment: @martineau I will try and understand why the HANDSHAKE dictionary isn't updated. Thank you so much for your answers, they were really helpful

Comment: For troubleshooting, you might want to simplify your problem a lot. See if you can separate out the issue you're having with the output from the logic that controls the packet sniffing. Try *hard coding* a batch of data (maybe a packet or a connection, I don't know `pcap` either) and *only* running the code to parse and dump it to a file. Does it work as expected? If the json dumping code *does* work in isolation, then maybe the sniffing code is giving it bad data (or just data in a different format than it expects).

Comment: @Blckknght It works because when I try and print the data that I give to the HANDSHAKE at parse_client_hello function it is the correct data that is parsed.
For example, when I print : tls_dictionary('tls_version',client.version) it is the correct data which means that what I affect to HANDSHAKE["Client_Hello"]['Version'] is correct. But what I don't understand is that : Why the dictionary isn't updated when I affect the value? And I think that this is the main problem that the json_read() isn't showing the right values,because the dictionary is not updated when I affect values

Comment: Can you `print(HANDSHAKE)` in both functions (e.g. at the end of `parse_client_hello` and the top of `json_read`)?

Comment: @Blckknght I just tried it, it works!!! finally! thank you so much